# Deref Mutex/RwLock to inner object with implicit locking

Tags: rust, synchronization, locking, traits, dereference

I have a struct `Obj` with a large API that I would also like to use through an `Arc<RwLock<Obj>>`. I have defined a `struct ObjRef(Arc<RwLock<Obj>>)` and want to call functions of `Obj` on `ObjRef` without needing to call `.read().unwrap()` or `.write().unwrap()` every time. (`ObjRef` implements `Deref<Target=Arc<RwLock<Obj>>`, so I only have to call `objRef.read().unwrap()`)

I could implement all of the functions of `Obj` again for `ObjRef` in a manner like this:

```rust
impl ObjRef {
    fn foo(&self, arg: Arg) -> Ret {
        self.read().unwrap().foo(arg)
    }
}
```

But doing this for every function results in a lot of boilerplate.

Implementing `Deref<Target=Obj>` for `ObjRef` does not work, because the `deref` implementation would be returning a reference into the `RwReadLockGuard` object returned by `.read().unwrap()` which would be dropped after `deref`:

```rust
impl Deref for ObjRef {
    type Target = Obj;
    fn deref(&self) -> &Self::Target {
        let guard: RwLockReadGuard<'_, Obj> = self.0.read().unwrap();
        &*guard // <- return reference to Obj referenced by guard
        // guard is dropped now, reference lifetime ends
    }
}
```

Is there a way to call the `Obj` Api through a low boilerplate implementation doing the locking internally?

I am thinking about introducing a trait for the Api with a default implementation of the Api and a single function to be implemented by users of the trait for getting a generic `Deref<Target=Obj>`, but this puts the Api under some limitations, for example using generic parameters will become much more complicated.

Is there maybe a better way, something that lets me use any `Obj` through a lock without explicitly calling the locking mechanism every time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible to do this through `Deref`, because `Deref::deref` always returns a plain reference — the validity of it must only depend on the argument continuing to exist (which the borrow checker understands), not on any additional state such as "locked".

Also, adding locking generically to an interface designed without it is dangerous, because it may accidentally cause deadlocks, or allow unwanted outcomes due to doing two operations in sequence that should have been done using a *single* locking.

I recommend considering making your type *internally* an `Arc<RwLock`, that is,

```rust
pub struct Obj {
    lock: Arc<RwLock<ObjData>>,
}

// internal helper, not public
struct ObjData {
    // whatever fields Obj would have had go here
}
```

Then, you can define your methods once, directly on `Obj`, and the caller never needs to deal with the lock explicitly, but your methods can handle it exactly as needed. This is a fairly common pattern in problem domains that benefit from it, like UI objects.

If there is some reason why `Obj` really needs to be usable with or without the lock, then define a trait.

Comment: My main concern was worse performance when the locks aren't really needed. But you are right that I should probably handle the locking more conciously. The way I do it now is that I moved the functions that require locking into the `ObjRef` type (with the `Arc<RwLock<Obj>>` internally) and implemented `Deref<Target=Arc<RwLock<Obj>>` on it. So I have to use `ObjRef` to use the concurrent functions but can still use the remaining API by locking the whole structure.